# How do I enable the function keys on the Touch Bar for Spyder by default?

Tags: spyder, miniconda, macbookpro-touch-bar

I have installed python 3.7.7 and Spyder 4.1.2 on my MacBook (macOS 10.15.4) using miniconda. As far as I understand, Spyder is not a stand-alone app, but runs through python. Hence, I followed [these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44348973/4772635) so that Spyder is recognized as an App by macOS. This is working, and I can use the function keys on the Touch Bar by pressing `fn`, but I cannot get Spyder to use the function keys on the Touch Bar by default. When I follow the [official steps by Apple](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT207240), I can select the Spyder 'app' from the menu, but then I get the error

> You cannot add keyboard shortcuts for the application spyder.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I am stuck with the same issue as well. Did you find a solution? Please post the same if you did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the personal edition of Anaconda (1.9.12) on MacOs 10.15.6, I was able to make the Fn keys appear in Spyder (launched through Anaconda-Navigator).

I used Keyboard->Shortcuts->Function Keys and added /Users/USER/opt/anaconda3/python

Best wishes