# macOS, Spyder works but spyder.app doesn't start anymore

Tags: macos, spyder

I installed python and spyder on my Mac with homebrew and pip. I am using macOS Catalina and zsh. Yesterday, the app was working, I shut down the pc in the evening, and today it doesn't work. And yes I tried to turn it off and on again :)

Some information on my install:

```
mathieu@tsf-452-wpa-3-213 MacOS % which python3
/usr/local/bin/python3

mathieu@tsf-452-wpa-3-213 MacOS % which spyder3
/usr/local/bin/spyder3
```

And the zsh config file: `nano ~/.zshrc`

```
alias pip=/usr/local/bin/pip3
alias pip3=/usr/local/bin/pip3
alias python=/usr/local/bin/python3
function runpy() {
    python "$@"
}
alias pynfb="runpy '/Users/mathieu/Documents/NFB Lab/pynfb/main.py'"
alias nfb="runpy '/Users/mathieu/Documents/NFB Lab/pynfb/main.py'"
alias neurodecode="runpy '/Users/mathieu/Documents/NeuroDecode/neurodecode/gui/$

export NEUROD_ROOT=/Users/mathieu/Documents/NeuroDecode
export NEUROD_DATA=/Users/mathieu/Documents/NeuroDecode/SubjectData
export NEUROD_SCRIPTS=/Users/mathieu/Documents/NeuroDecode/SubjectScripts
```

In the terminal, the command `spyder3` does start spyder perfectly. I created an app with the great SO answer of topoman available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44348973/8324480). The app bounces once or twice and then disappear/doesn't start.

Just in case I delete my `spyder.app` folder and all its content and recreated one with the procedure described by topoman where I also changed the `s` to be capital this time.

```
mathieu@tsf-452-wpa-3-213 Spyder.app % ls
Contents    Icon?

mathieu@tsf-452-wpa-3-213 Contents % ls
Info.plist  MacOS

mathieu@tsf-452-wpa-3-213 MacOS % nano spyder
#!/bin/bash
/usr/local/bin/spyder3 $@
```

And `Info.plist` is a copy-paste from the answer of topoman. Any idea how I can fix the app? Or at least how I can get the mac to display an error message to then fix it?

Comment: And one more point: going into Spyder.app/Contents/MacOS and double clicking on spyder (on the executable within the .app bundle) does start spyder properly..

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) I can't help you with your question because it's a hack that I don't know how it works. However, I just want to tell you we're creating a proper macOS Spyder app for our next version (4.2), to be released in November.

Comment: @CarlosCordoba I am very glad it will be coming! Thank you for letting me know!

Comment: No problem. We finally understood that a huge roadblock that prevents more people to adopt Spyder is the lack of self-contained, simple to install apps for macOS and Windows.

Comment: @CarlosCordoba And out of curiosity, would it be possible to install this app (on windows, or macOS) by a download and by pip as well? On windows as on mac, I do prefer to use pip for anything python related.

Comment: These apps will be independent of pip and conda. You'll need to download its dmg or exe installers from Github.